# Why does this NOT IN query work as intended, but not this NOT EXISTS query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, exists, not-exists

Working (NOT IN) retrieves 3 rows:

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d , Company c3
WHERE d.deviceid NOT IN
(
    Select d1.deviceid from Device d1, Clone x1 
    WHERE  d1.deviceid =  x1.deviceID 
    AND  
    (
        x1.XPath = 'hi' 
        OR x1.XPath = 'bye' 
    )
    AND 
    ( 
        EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('T130SF0W2050', ',')) as s 
        WHERE x1.Value like '%' + s.items + '%' )
    ) 
)  
AND  
d.companyid = c3.companyid and c3.companynumber in (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('00223200', ','))
```

Not Working(not exists):

```
select DISTINCT d.* from Device d , Company c3
WHERE  NOT EXISTS
(Select * from Device d1, Clone x1 
    WHERE  d1.deviceid =  x1.deviceID 
    AND  
    (
        x1.XPath = 'hi' 
        OR x1.XPath = 'bye' 
    )
    AND 
    ( 
        EXISTS ( select * from (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('T130SF0W2050', ',')) as s 
        WHERE x1.Value like '%' + s.items + '%' )
    )

)  
AND  
d.companyid = c3.companyid and c3.companynumber in (SELECT * FROM [dbo].[Split] ('00223200', ','))
```

I'm unsure I'm using the exists syntax correct, what should I select from the subquery? I've tried a few different combinations. It won't run if I put `WHERE d.deviceid NOT EXISTS`

Solution (thanks to Nikola):

add `AND d1.deviceid = d.deviceid` inside the Exists subquery.

Comment: `Exists` variant is not correlated to `d`. As it is now it always returns true if any row from `d1, x1` satisfies conditions. Add `and d1.DeviceID = d.DeviceID`.

Comment: Ugh, why are you using old-style joins?

Comment: Nikola you should put your comment as an answer so I can mark the question correct.

Comment: Please don't edit the solution into the question. This makes the question no longer useful.

Answer (score 1):

The difference is that the NOT IN query returns devices that match the company and don't match the inner query specification.

For the NOT EXIST query to work as written (where "work as written" refers to returning the same result as the top query), there can't be any devices that exist matching the inner query. If any devices match the inner query **at all**, the query won't return any results.